# A homework about growth rate of function

Tags: function, big-o

Please order the function belows by growth rate

```
n ^ 1.5
n ^ 0.5 + log n
n log ^ 2 n
n log ( n ^ 2 )
n log log n
n ^ 2 + log n
n log n
n
```

ps:
Ordering by growth rate means, as n gets larger and larger, which function will eventually be higher in value than the others.

ps2. I have ordered most of the functions:
n , n log log n, n log n, n log^2 n, n log ( n ^ 2 ), n ^ 1.5

I just do not know how to order:
n ^ 2 + log n,
n ^ 0.5 + log n,
these 2 values

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Plug `n = several million` into each and see which comes out the highest?

Answer (score 5):

You can figure this out fairly easily by graphing the functions and seeing which ones get larger (find a graphing calculator, check out [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), or try graphing the functions on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/PlottingAndGraphics.html)).  Or, or course, you just pick some large value of n and compare the various functions, but graphs can give a bit of a better picture.

Answer (score 3):

The key to the answer you seek is that when you sum two functions, their combined "growth rate" is going to be exactly that of the one with the higher growth rate of the two. So, you now know the growth rates of these two functions, since you appear (from knowing the correct ordering of all the others) to know the proper ordering of the growth rates that are in play here.

Answer (score 3):

Plugging in a large number is not the correct way to approach this!

Since you have the order of growth, then you can use the following rules http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/Alsalih/CSC311_10_11_01/3.3_GrowthofFunctionsAndAsymptoticNotations.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In all of those cases, you're dealing with pairs of functions that themselves have different growth rates.

With that in mind, only the larger one really matters, since it will be most dominant even with a sum. So in each of those function sums, which is the bigger one and how does it compare to the other ones on your larger list?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to proof mathematically, you should try something like this.

If you have two functions, e.g.:

```
f1(n) = n log n
f2(n) = n
```

You can simply find the limit of f3(n) = f1(n)/f2(n) when n tends to infinity.

If the result is zero, then f2(n) has a greater growth rate than f1(n).

On the other hand, if the result is infinity then f1(n) has a greater growth rate than f2(n).

Answer (score 0):

n<sup>0.5</sup> (or n<sup>1/2</sup>) is the square root of n. So, it grows more slowly than n<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

```
let say n = 4 then we get 
n ^ 2 + log n       = 16.6020599913
n ^ 1.5             =  8
n                   =  4
n log ( n ^ 2 )     =  4.81
n ^ 0.5 + log n     =  2.60205999133
n log n             =  2.4
n log ^ 2 n         = ? 
n log log n         = -0.8
```

Comment: The growth rate of a function is looking at values as `n` goes to infinity.  Using ridiculously large `n` values can help.  Using `n=4` will not.